# Database created but no tables in MySQL Docker

Tags: mysql, database, docker, tomcat

I have a Application run into a tomcat-embededd container and linked with a MySQL database

I have running my container by

> docker-compose up --build -d

, the two container is up, i can log in to the application

But , when i put

> docker exec -it myapp-mysql bash

and i choise my database with

> use dbname;

, i don't see any table into my database

This is my docker-compose

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    container_name: myapp-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXX
      MYSQL_DATABASE: XXXXXXX
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: A.B.C.D
 back-end-java:
    container_name: myapp-tomcat
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    image: application
    ports:
      - 8008:8443
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: A.B.C.D
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet:  A.B.C.D/24
        gateway:  A.B.C.D
```

and this is the Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.33-jre8

ADD myapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Thank YOU

Comment: I don't see where you link your db container with your data, or do you store all data inside container?

Comment: I don't see where any code that creates database

Comment: so, How resolve this?

Comment: links:
      - db 

this is the link

Comment: Links is only for establishing a  network link, which has been deprecated since compose links the containers automatically. The default mysql image creates an empty database. So to repeat what Khang & vinay said, where are you creating the tables?

Comment: i store all data inside container

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you added docker volumes in docker-compose.yaml, like following :

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    container_name: myapp-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXX
      MYSQL_DATABASE: XXXXXXX
    volumes:
      # Initialize database on container start
      - ./products.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/products.sql
      - products-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: A.B.C.D

...
```

In my case, I got database initialized without tables in MySQL instance because I misplaced the SQL file. It was placed in another directory, like below :

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    container_name: myapp-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXX
      MYSQL_DATABASE: XXXXXXX
    volumes:
      # Initialize database on container start
      - ./database/products.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/products.sql
      - products-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: A.B.C.D

...
```

Having said that, I recommend you to **carefully look at where you stored database** because as development goes by, **you might have moved it to under particular directory** instead of placing it in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `--build` which means you force the recreation of mysql container and since you are not mounting your data volume to the host machine, your data will be wiped out each time you run this command. you can avoid that by mounting mysql data volume to your docker-compose as the following:

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    container_name: myapp-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - "./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXX
      MYSQL_DATABASE: XXXXXXX
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: A.B.C.D
```